# “To sense a pattern” or “to sense a theme” in German?

Tags: expression

Is there an expression for *to sense a pattern* or *to sense a theme* in German? Meaning, for example, that we start observing similar things, or that we seem to be repeating the same behaviour, etc.

(Boring) example:

> Two weeks ago, I ordered an internet router, and was told that I had to call back last week. Last week, I called and was told to call this week. This week, I was told to call next week. I’m starting to sense a pattern here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

> Ein Muster (zu) erkennen.

Your example would be

> Ich beginne ein Muster zu erkennen

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Alon Dattners answer.

In colloquial speech, I would prefer

> Ich sehe langsam ein Muster.

and @JimmyB added

> Dahinter scheint System zu stecken.

as another translation, indicating that what's repeatedly happening appears to be not coincidental but the result of some hidden intention of the other party.

Comment: What do you think of of replacing Muster by System like: "Dahinter steckt ein System."

Comment: @DanFromGermany, your example with "System" works, too. However,  "System" and "Muster" are not generally exchangable. Enother example would be: "Ich entdecke ein System"

Comment: "Dahinter scheint System zu stecken." (coll.) would be a rather free translation, indicating that what's repeatedly happening appears to be not coincidental but the result of some hidden intention of the other party.

Comment: @JimmyB, also a good translation! I added it to my answer.